# How to avoid dropping schemas when publishing DB in SSDT Database project

Tags: ssdt, database-projects

When publishing a database from SSDT, there are several options to "do not drop" an object if it is not in the SSDT project. However, it seems that there is no option to avoid dropping schemas. Does anyone know if this is possible to achieve, or do I have to manually edit the published script?

This is the problem when I choose to "do not drop tables", but then it will try to drop schemas that have tables in them.

br
Gert

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer

> DeploymentPlanModifier for SqlPackager.exe to filter what actual gets deployed from a dacpac, you can choose to ignore or keep specific objects or types

And choose to keep schema's and it won't drop them anymore.

---

MS now has support for it [SQL Server on Codeplex](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/sql-server-on-codeplex/ba-p/387333)

Comment: This link is no longer active